# Javascript - Execute 2 functions after triggering 1 eventListener

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps

Im making a googleMaps like application, and i need it to execute two functions when an image within the application is clicked.
The first function shows a content string with the name of the object
The second shows directions from the users current location to the clicked object.

```
// Creating separate markers and locations
    // King Tuts
    var tutsImg = "kingTutsIcon.jpg";
    var kingTuts = new google.maps.LatLng(55.86256, -4.265);
    var tutsDisplay = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: kingTuts,
    map: map,
    icon: tutsImg,
    title:"King Tut's Wah Wah Hut"
    });

    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
    '</div>'+
    '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">King Tuts Wah Wah Hut</h2>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
    '</div>'+
    '</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         content: contentString
    });


    // Creating directions

    function calcRoute () {
            var request = {
            origin: marker, 
            destination: kingTuts,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
         }

        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
        }

    google.maps.event.addListener(tutsDisplay, 'click', function() {
         infowindow.open(map,tutsDisplay);

    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(tutsDisplay, 'click', function() {
         infowindow.open(map,calcRoute);

    });
```

This is the code that creates the different variables that are used within the two functions. 
However, the application only executes the first function (the display of the name), and doesnt show the directions which are meant to come up after the second function is executed.

Please help guys, im really stumped here

Comment: removing previous comments.. your issue is not with adding event listeners.. it's with how you're attempting to use calcRoute and directionsService (which is undefined in your code), as well as directionsDisplay(also undefined).

Answer (score 0):

The [google.maps.InfoWindow.open](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) takes two arguments:

```
open(map?:Map|StreetViewPanorama, anchor?:MVCObject) | None | Opens this InfoWindow on the given map. Optionally, an InfoWindow can be associated with an anchor. In the core API, the only anchor is the Marker class. However, an anchor can be any MVCObject that exposes a LatLng position property and optionally a Point anchorPoint property for calculating the pixelOffset (see InfoWindowOptions). The anchorPoint is the offset from the anchor's position to the tip of the InfoWindow.
```

calcRoute  is a function, not a MVCObject, not sure what you expect to happen.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(tutsDisplay, 'click', function() {
     infowindow.open(map,calcRoute);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Referencing https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var haight = new google.maps.LatLng(37.7699298, -122.4469157);
var oceanBeach = new google.maps.LatLng(37.7683909618184, -122.51089453697205);
function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: haight
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

function calcRoute() {
  var selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").value;
  var request = {
      origin: haight,
      destination: oceanBeach,
      // Note that Javascript allows us to access the constant
      // using square brackets and a string value as its
      // "property."
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}
```

## **According the above sample.. you need to initialize these objects**

```
directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionServices()
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer()
```

.. after the map is loaded into your page.. you need to perform the following method.

```
directionsDisplay.setMap(map)
```

***In your sample.. replace the following***

```
google.maps.event.addListener(tutsDisplay, 'click', function() {
         infowindow.open(map,tutsDisplay);

    });
```

with

```
google.maps.event.addListener(tutsDisplay, 'click', function() {
         directionsDisplay.setMap(map)
         infowindow.open(map,tutsDisplay);
         calcRoute();    
    });
```

and remove the redundant google.maps.event.addListener declaration/assignment.

Comment: Note: this is not optimum.. because directionDisplay.setMap is being called on each click.. where it is probably better to set it in an initialization function, like the GoogleMap sample suggests.